# Issue with ls -l *.xml command not working in one directory

Tags: linux

I'm running into a strange issue.  I am trying to execute an `ls -l *.xml` in a particular directory however when I do this, I'm getting the message

```
ls: invalid option -- .
Try ls --help' for more information.
```

If I do something like `ls -l *.php` or `ls -l *.txt` it works fine in the same directory where I receive the invalid option message above. What's even stranger to me is that if I do `ls -l *.xml` in any other directory, it works fine and does not give the Invalid Option message as it does in the one directory.

I've tried doing `ls -l *.xml` in the directory as both root and my normal login and it yields the same invalid option message.

```
type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=tty'

which ls
alias ls='ls --color=tty'
    /bin/ls

whereis ls
ls: /bin/ls /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1p/ls.1p.gz
```

Am I losing my mind?  What could be going wrong? Why would `ls -l *.xml` not work in one directory but work fine in others?

Edit:

Tried piping ls -l to grep but got this error.  Not sure why I would ever need to pipe it to grep though, as `ls -l *.xml` works in any other directory no problem.  Never needed to grep it before.

```
ls -l | grep .xml
grep: invalid option -- .
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
```

Comment: What files are in your directory? Give us an `ls -la` please. I guess there's a file whose name is starting with `--` or similar.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what the problem was.  

After carefully looking through the entire contents of the directory, I found a file named literally `-.xml`.  Apparently the dash in the filename was causing issues.  In fact, I couldn't even delete the file via `rm -.xml` as the filename was causing `rm` to fail. 

I had to go into the directory via a graphical SFTP client and delete it that one.  Once the file was removed, it all seems to be working again.

Comment: Some quick observations. '**-**' precedes alphanumerics in the normal collating sequence, so _-.xml_ would usually be first when **bash** expands the file mask; this is done before **ls** sees its parameters: it cannot distinguish an expanded file name from an entered string. Like other commands **ls** accepts "**--**" for end of options, so `ls -l -- *.xml` works. I cannot reproduce your **grep** error, but `ls -l | grep *.xml` gave a similar error. The command should be `ls -l | grep '\.xml$'`: your command finds names like _AxmlB_ (always single-quote search strings with non-alphanumerics).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `*.xml` glob will be expanded to all `.xml` files in the current directory, I assume that the glob will be expanded to something that is parsed as

```
ls -l -- .....
```

or similar, i.e. a file starting with `--`.

Try to find out what that file is by doing a simple listing with `ls -la`.

Try to remove said file with `rm -- --filename` — here the `--` is needed if you want the filename not to be parsed as an option. Alternatively you could remove it from a GUI, or with `rm "--filename"`.

Answer (score -2):

Try `ls -l | grep .xml`. I am not sure how something like ls -l *.xml can work in the first place because I am under the impression that if you are attempting to narrow down your results to a single file format, usually piping and grep would help..

Comment: Thanks, but still not working.  See my edit above.  I'm doing some more digging and I think I see what the problem might be now.

Comment: This is a little inaccurate / not true. `ls -l *.xml` will of course work, because the `*.xml` glob will be expanded to all XML files in the current directory, so the command `ls -l foo.xml bar.xml baz.xml ...` will be run.

Comment: Ahh oook. Thanks for the clarification. I always piped/grep when I was looking for particular files/formats

Comment: Yeah, that's not really needed. It's also prone to errors if you want to work with the filenames later on, e.g. looping over them. You can just do `for f in *.xml; do…` instead of `for f in $(ls | grep .xml); do…`